# Differences between IntelliJ JUnit test runner and Gradle JUnit test runner on Linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit

We have a Java project with corresponding JUnit test suite which we intend to run on the Linux platform. It has been developed using Windows without any problems.

When running our unit test suite using `gradle test` on Linux, floating point differences start to appear. There also seems to be a difference between the IntelliJ test runner and the Gradle built-in one.

JDK used: Sun JDK 1.8u91 x64

```
Running tests using 'gradle test' on Linux:             ERRORS (see below)
Running tests using IntelliJ test runner on Linux:      OK
Running tests using 'gradle test' on Windows:           OK
Running tests using IntelliJ test runner on Windows:    OK

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<-2.18> but was:<-2.1652631074322057>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1.11> but was:<1.1376954128942385>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<373.32> but was:<375.4870142751794>
```

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet of the code under test? I suggest you use `java.math.BigDecimal` if you want to avoid floating point issues

Answer (score 0):

The critial section is:

```
final double amountInEUR = (amountInOtherCurrency - (quantity * commission)) * (closePrice * closePriceMultiplier);
```

As you can see, it is a financial application. Some research on BigDecimal indeed turn up that's the way to go. Thank you Lance Java!